# Get youtube videos from given search keywords

Tags: php, youtube

There are a lot site which are exactly like youtube in function but they depend on youtube , they search for your keyword ,get the videos list and play the video within their server without moving to youtube.com.
I want to know how to do so.
Example site is,
playit.pk

Answer (score 0):

Google has published a whole site explaining the Google/Youtube API. It can be found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php

This API hast everything you need, it just takes some time :)

EDIT: This might help you as well: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference